# SQL FLOAT TO VARCHAR with lengthy decimal values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Input value to the procedure (Float) = `999999.98999999999`

Inside the procedure, I am converting the `float` to `VARCHAR(15)`, While conversion the value become `1000000` but is need an Output = `999999.99`.

Not able to use `Substring()`, `Charindex()`.

Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Are Floating Point Numbers Inaccurate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate)

Comment: No the share link is different from query. The link did not answer my query. Thanks for your information but I am sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`STR()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527(v=sql.120).aspx) function for that:

```
declare @floatValue float = 999999.98999999999
declare @varcharValue varchar(15) = STR(@floatValue, 12, 2)
```

or [`CONVERT()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=sql.120).aspx)

```
CONVERT (VARCHAR(15), @floatValue, 128)
```